# Cannot change font size in org-agenda in fresh emacs installation

Tags: init-file, org-agenda, faces

After running this in my shell:

```
$ sudo dnf -y remove emacs
$ sudo dnf clean all
$ rm -f ~/.emacs
$ rm -r ~/.emacs.d
$ sudo dnf -y install emacs
$ emacs foo.org           # existent file
```

Then, within emacs `C-c [`; file added to agenda files. I close emacs.

Then I open emacs in the shell:

```
$ emacs --eval "(org-agenda-list)" --eval "(delete-other-windows)"
```

and try to increase the font size with: `C-x C--` or `C-x C-=`.

I get this message:

```
text-scale-adjust: Symbol’s value as variable is void: text-scale-mode
```

And the font size does not change. I have this behavior in two different machines, one Ubuntu, the other Fedora. I have searched for a solution for days, but perhaps because of my lisp illiteracy, I cannot relate similar posts with my problem.

---

If I input `M-x text-scale-set RET`, the font increases a bit, and now I can use `C-x C--` and `C-x C-=`. If I open other files (for example the welcome buffer) `C-x C--` and `C-x C-=` work well. I don't get why this happens.

---

Version:

```
$ emacs --version          
GNU Emacs 27.1
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Which version of Emacs?

Comment: info added as edit in the question: version 27.1

Comment: That does seem strange.  `text-scale-adjust` is autoloaded in Emacs 27.1 and that same library defines `text-scale-mode`.  Perhaps check that `face-remap.el` has been byte-compiled (or just recompile it).

Comment: This problem does not have anything to do with `org-agenda`, so it probably should not have the `org-agenda` tag. BTW, note parenthetically that `C-c [` adds the current file to the `org-agenda-files` variable *for the current session only*. If you want it permanently added, you need to customize the variable or set it in your init file.

Comment: I though the problem was related to org-agenda because that was the only mode that had the issue. On any other mode I could change the text size. I ended up removing everything and adding packages one by one. Once I get time I will try to write an answer.

Comment: Now I'm curious: do tell :-)

Comment: I will write an answer later, I will put it on my agenda... on my org-agenda... hahha. Thanks :)